# Cursor type in Texstudio pdf viewer panel

Tags: texstudio, viewers

Now here is a potentially stupid question about something that has really been annoying me recently. In the pdf viewer panel in Texstudio, there are two buttons in the toolbar that change your type of cursor: a magnifying glass and a blue scroll 'cross-arrow'. If you never click on any of the two buttons, your cursor is the standard (Windows) white arrow cursor. I made the mistake of clicking on the magnifying glass, and there seems to be no way of getting my nice white arrow cursor back - instead I am stuck with either of the two Texstudio cursor types and I find them very ugly. There is no button to choose the standard cursor, nor does it revert if you open and close the panel, or Texstudio itself. Any help?

Comment: It could be a bug or at least a bad UX choice. You should maybe consider sending this as feedback to the creators of this app.

Comment: I just installed the latest version just to test it. I installed the app from scratch and opened the PDF viewer without clicking anything else. I found that the default cursor is the magnifying glass, so there is no "third option" with the default Windows cursor at all.